# Auto increment in Symfony?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony project in which I want to auto increment the value in one column in a mysql database.
However this is not an id column - I just always want the first value in the table to be one (whereas with an id style column each value is always unique - so if you have a table that had 20 rows, and then deleted those rows, the first value would still be 21).  Is there a simple way of doing this in Symfony?
Many thanks!

Comment: this has nothing to do with symfony, irrelevant tag

Comment: to answer your question - no, there is not. You will have to manually reindex the records for them to always start with 1. Write a script for that if you must, but I'd strongly suggest against it. What is the purpose? Eye-candy?